# How to use Jenkins Build Keeper Plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, policy

I would like to use the Jenkins 'Build Keeper Plugin' but I don't know how. The plugin site doesn't describe how to use it. [Plugin Site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Keeper+Plugin)

On this [page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+points) I found the extension points which I would like to use, e.g. the `org.jenkins_ci.plugins.build_keeper.KeepFirstFailedPolicy`

But in the configuration part of my project, I can't find any place to configure it to use that policy. So where do I have to add it?

Jenkins version is 1.544

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to open Job configuration page and look for settings ?

For example it is another plugin but it is very similar : Build Discard plugin, may be you will use it for your purposes:

[Build discard old build settings](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/65670518/discardOldBuild_conf2.png?version=1&modificationDate=1359279572000)

Comment: Thanks, I guess the 'keeper plugin' is not compatible. I installed now the discard plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in the job under the section Build Environment.

For screenshots see also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25293

Answer (score 0):

If used from within a pipeline, it is enough to write
'currentBuild.rawBuild.keepLog(true)'

That is unfortunately not an interface to the plugin, just a jobs setting, but can solve it when You want to keep all builds, or decide within the build if to keep it.